# ZSH vcs_info: How to indicate if there are untracked files in Git

Tags: git, zsh

In my zsh configuration, I have the following settings for `vcs_info`:

```
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' check-for-changes true
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' unstagedstr '!'
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' stagedstr '+'
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats "%u%c"
```

Using these settings, when I am in a git repository that contains unstaged changes, a `!` will be displayed in the prompt. When there are staged changes, a `+` will be displayed in the prompt.

This is all good, but how do I make zsh indicate, for example `?`, when there are untracked files in the repository?

I could not find a built-in setting for this in the zsh manual. Is there a way to get an indication if there are untracked files in a Git repository?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the source of zsh there is good example of showing `T` mark to prompt when there is untracked file: [Misc/vcs_info_examples](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/f9e9dce5443f323b340303596406f9d3ce11d23a/Misc/vcs_info-examples#L155-L170)

```
### Display the existence of files not yet known to VCS

### git: Show marker (T) if there are untracked files in repository
# Make sure you have added staged to your 'formats':  %c
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*+set-message:*' hooks git-untracked

+vi-git-untracked(){
    if [[ $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2> /dev/null) == 'true' ]] && \
        git status --porcelain | grep '??' &> /dev/null ; then
        # This will show the marker if there are any untracked files in repo.
        # If instead you want to show the marker only if there are untracked
        # files in $PWD, use:
        #[[ -n $(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard) ]] ; then
        hook_com[staged]+='T'
    fi
}
```

You can just copy & paste from here, but I wrote a slight modification version which uses [misc](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/f9e9dce5443f323b340303596406f9d3ce11d23a/Functions/VCS_Info/VCS_INFO_formats#L37-L50) instead of adding character to `staged`.

```
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats "%u%c%m"
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*+set-message:*' hooks git-untracked

+vi-git-untracked() {
  if [[ $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2> /dev/null) == 'true' ]] && \
     git status --porcelain | grep -m 1 '^??' &>/dev/null
  then
    hook_com[misc]='?'
  fi
}
```

`%m` in format corresponds to character in `hook_com[misc]`.
Also just grepping whole the output of `git status --porcelain`, instead it may be faster using `grep -m 1` (depends on how the standard output is buffered or how `git status --porcelain` is implemented).

Comment: For Debian/Ubuntu users, the example is also available at `/usr/share/doc/zsh-common/examples/Misc/vcs_info-examples.gz`

Comment: how does the "hooks git-untracked" knows it is bound to "+vi-git-untracked()" ?

Comment: @sigz according to the [document](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#vcs_005finfo-Hooks), 
`In order to avoid namespace problems, all registered function names are prepended by a ‘+vi-’, so the actual functions called for the ‘foo’ hook are ‘+vi-bar’ and ‘+vi-baz`

Comment: Note that the `-m` option for grep is not specified by POSIX, although it is present in both GNU and FreeBSD's grep implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The post by ymonad is a neat solution, but I'm posting an answer because of the lighbulb it prompted in me.

I found it helps to remember that a `.zshrc` file is just a shell script - you can treat it like the terminal. So, read `man git` to see what's available to you to gather the information you need. You can then simply query git in a function or the like in your `.zshrc`. Like so:

```bash
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats "%u%c%m"
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*+set-message:*' hooks untracked-git

+vi-untracked() {
  if [[ -n "$(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard)" ]]; then
      hook_com[misc]='?'
  else
      hook_com[misc]=''
  fi
}
```

When I realised that I could treat the `.zshrc` file like a shell script (duh), I realised I could just copy over what had worked for me in bash. So, the above is exactly the same if statement I have in my `.bashrc` to look for the presence of untracked files.

Comment: this will not obey gitignore after a quick test

Comment: The proper argument to ls-files is `--exclude-standard`

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just me, but I'm not getting any output for this, whatsoever.